# Recursively change a JSON data structure in Haskell

Tags: json, haskell

I am trying to write a function that will take a JSON object, make a change to every string value in it and return a new JSON object.  So far my code is:

```
applyContext :: FromJSON a => a -> a
applyContext x =
  case x of
    Array _  -> map applyContext x
    Object _ -> map applyContext x
    String _ -> parseValue x
    _        -> x
```

However, the compiler complains about second second `case` line:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[b0]' with actual type `a'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      applyContext :: forall a. FromJSON a => a -> a
    at app\Main.hs:43:17
```

I'm guessing that is because `map` is meant to work on lists, but I would have naively expected it to use `Data.HashMap.Lazy.map` instead, since that is what the type actually is in that case. If I explicitly use that function I get

```
Couldn't match expected type `HashMap.HashMap k0 v20' with actual type `a'
```

which also makes sense, since I haven't constrained `a` to that extent because then it wouldn't work for the other cases. I suspect that if I throw enough explicit types at this I could make it work but it feels like it should be a lot simpler.  What is an idiomatic way of writing this function, or if this is good then what would be the simplest way of getting the types right?

Comment: You call `map`, not `Data.HashMap.Lazy.map`; Haskell doesn't try to second guess you just because you provided an argument of the wrong type.

Comment: The idiomatic approach starts at the type and says "does this even make sense?" As far as I can tell, it doesn't.  It seems like at the minimum, it also needs a `ToJSON` constraint on `a`.  I'd start by writing a working function of type `Value -> Value` and then a second function that does conversions back and forth between arbitrary types and `Value`. Doing that would also make it clear why you need both constraints.

Comment: And for what it's worth, this is the sort of problem that `lens` and `lens-aeson` solve very cleanly - but I can see why you'd want to avoid that for a while.

Comment: @Carl That should probably be an answer

Comment: @Carl Thanks, as soon as I read it it made perfect sense that I would need a ToJSON constraint. I don't understand what you mean by a function that does a conversion to `Value` though - isn't `a` already a `Value`?

Comment: Your function is already ill-typed regardless of the contents of the right-hand sides. You have a value of type `a` (a type variable) and try to pattern match on concrete constructors on that value - type variables never have concrete constructors. It looks like you want `case toJSON x of ...` - there is no automatic type casting in Haskell, which seems to be what you are expecting (if this is the case, perhaps a basic Haskell refresher is in order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what `FromJSON a => a` does mean? It's type of some thing what says: it can be thing with any type but only from class `FromJSON`. This class can contain types which very differently constructed and you can't do any pattern matching. You can only do what is specified in the class `FromJSON` declaration by programmer. Basically, there is one method `parseJSON :: FromJSON a => Value -> Parser a`.

Secondly, you should use some isomorphic representation of JSON for your work. The type `Value` is good one. So, you can do the main work by the function like `Value -> Value`. After that, you can compose this fuction with `parseJSON` and `toJSON` for generalse types.

Like this:

```
change :: Value -> Value
change (Array x)  = Array . fmap change $ x
change (Object x) = Object . fmap change $ x
change (String x) = Object . parseValue $ x
change x          = x

apply :: (ToJSON a, FromJSON b) => (Value -> Value) -> a -> Result b
apply change = fromJSON . change . toJSON

unsafeApply :: (ToJSON a, FromJSON b) => (Value -> Value) -> a -> b
unsafeApply change x = case apply change x of
                         Success x -> x
                         Error msg -> error $ "unsafeApply: " ++ msg

applyContext :: (ToJSON a, FromJSON b) => a -> b
applyContext = unsafeApply change
```

You can write more complicated transformations like `Value -> Value` with [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) and [lens-aeson](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-aeson). For example:

```
import Control.Lens
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Lens
import Data.Text.Lens
import Data.Char

change :: Value -> Value
change = execState go
  where
    go = do
        zoom values go
        zoom members go
        _String . _Text . each %= toUpper
        _Bool %= not
        _Number *= 10

main = print $ json & _Value %~ change
  where json = "{\"a\":[1,\"foo\",false],\"b\":\"bar\",\"c\":{\"d\":5}}"
```

Output will be:

```
"{\"a\":[10,\"FOO\",true],\"b\":\"BAR\",\"c\":{\"d\":50}}"
```